# Sharepoint Online List Group heading links

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, grouping

I'm working in SharePoint Online - modern experience.  When creating a list with a group view the chevron (>) next to the group title will expand the group to show the contents with the other groups shown unexpanded. Clicking on the Group title will show that group only.

Is there a way to change the be behavior of the Group title link so that it does not show only it's contents?  Preferably have it expand the group contents as per the chevron link?

Answer (score 0):

I created a group by view in my test list and if I set "**By default, showing groupings**" to "Collapsed" in view settings, the list will be displayed like below.

[image]
[image]

If set it to "Expanded", the list will be displayed like this. Is this what you want?
[image]

Also, we can aovid redirecting to the one group only contents page by click the chevron (>) instead of clicking the group title.

Comment: Thr list will originally show collapsed, that's not a problem.  In your example clicking on Title will show the items only for that group.  I know that the chevron will expand, but the thousands of users on our Intranet won't know the difference between the chevron and Title link.  I want them to act the same.